Strict Serializable vs Serializable Transaction Latency and Throughput
Is the transaction latency and throughput performance in the distributed database with a consistency level of strict serializable significantly lower than serializable?
I'm already trying to understand the consistency level. My possible answer to this problem is that when the consistency level is higher, the transaction performance is lower. The effect is because the distributed database behaves in less concurrent/parallel and waits for the state to be ideal when executing the transaction.
Consistency level context:
https://jepsen.io/consistency
